# In Mahout how to generate itemId along with userId and preference value in matrix multiplication

Tags: mahout, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

We have two matrix:

- U->User feature which contains user's rating in accordance with the 20 feature of item (say movie is the item and its features may be-action, tragic..) 6x20.
- M->Item feature (contains item's feature ratings (say-if action, then its rating, if tragic....) 10x20).

Taking the dot product of both by using Mahout algo matrixmult. For each item it is displaying corresponding userId & prefValue. We need to generate the ItemId also along with them. The output is like this:

```
{1:2.8565926935818617,2:2.8814964873086852,3:2.3773543936434685,4:2.496325304186463,5:2.5705926376370076,6:2.1250241960704033}
{1:4.013041997061508,2:4.8002775481850515,3:3.9784440113314012,4:4.166481182599563,5:3.9695193417407655,6:3.1884041114544}
{1:3.651782747107523,2:4.388020478870542,3:4.779716339815735,4:4.1679196459740515,5:3.4571455995298668,6:3.173926716763791}
{1:1.460713098843009,2:1.755208191548217,3:1.9118865359262938,4:1.6671678583896208,5:1.3828582398119467,6:1.2695706867055168}
{1:0.7303565494215045,2:0.8776040957741085,3:0.9559432679631469,4:0.8335839291948104,5:0.6914291199059734,6:0.6347853433527582}
{1:3.665260265121202,2:4.392557489548237,3:3.9839325032084063,4:4.789440462322372,5:3.5796149241077186,6:2.899968609025724}
{1:1.4661041060484805,2:1.7570229958192944,3:1.5935730012833615,4:1.9157761849289485,5:1.4318459696430867,6:1.1599874436102895}
{1:2.7611810536133348,2:3.061568194855434,3:2.417510062701028,4:2.6187515401236525,5:2.8459602149193564,6:2.302795567224229}
{1:1.8407873690755552,2:2.0410454632369546,3:1.6116733751340164,4:1.745834360082434,5:1.8973068099462367,6:1.5351970448161516}
{1:1.7657295572889784,2:1.902295838215425,3:1.7169047303913343,4:1.6411563771362838,5:1.7813697244603068,6:1.880839700488139}
```

Where there are 6 users and 10 items. Here, for each item ,the user id n preference value is displayed but not the item id

Comment: i am wondering about this too